# Seaborn displot: How can I extract the histogram bin heights?

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, data-analysis

I am doing some work with `sns.displot` and have the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.displot(end_dist,
          bins=100,
            
          stat='probability',
              
          color='skyblue')
              
              
ax.set(xlabel='R_ee', ylabel='Probability')
```

where `end_dist` is a dataset I got from a simulation. From this I have the following plot which has been normalized so that the heights of all the bins sum to 1 (so the height of each bin is the probability of R_ee falling within said bin). I need to do some more calculations with these probabilities so want to extract the height of each and put in a numpy array. I am struggling to do this using seaborn's new displot.

[image: normalised histogram plot]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the density=True flag will give me bin values for a probability density function. This isn't what I want. Instead of the area under the curve summing to one, I would like the heights of the bins to sum to one like in my existing plot. Ofc I could calculate the area of each bin in a density plot to get this value myself but I wanted a more efficient method.

Comment: `bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(end_dist, bins='auto')`, then `values, _= np.histogram(end_dist, bins=bins)` and `values /= values.sum()`.  Instead of using `np.histogram_bin_edges(...)` you might want to create your own bin edges, e.g. `bins = np.arange(0.4, 3.6, 0.05)`.

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to get it working with this. For those that want to perform a similar analysis to me, the `density=True` flag needs to be added for the correct normalisation of the data.

Comment: Note that `stat='probability'` means that all the bar heights sum to 1, while `stat='density'` makes the total area of the bars summing to 1.  To get `stat='probability'`, you can do `values /= values.sum()`.

Comment: Yes, but in order to get the probability associated with each bin with `values /= values.sum()`, the area of the histogram must be equal to 1 (hence the `density=True` flag must be included in `np.histogram`. This can be checked at the end by summing the new values list and checking it equals 1, which it does when the flag is included for me.

Comment: Exactly. Note that your original example code used `stat='probability'`, so that is different.